# Is there a common pattern to represent a packet in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, packet

I'm developing a multiplayer game in C++ and I have a lot of different packet types I wish to exchange between the server and the clients. Is there some-kind of standard for those things? For example if I have a player position packet which contains the player's client id and position in the world's 3D space. Which method is more common/acceptable/standard?

```
struct PacketPlayerPosition
{
    char header;
    int clientID;
    float positionX;
    float positionY;
    float positionZ;
}
```

Or this way:

```
class PacketPlayerPosition
{
public:
    PacketPlayerPosition(int id, float x, float y, float z);
    PacketPlayerPosition(char* rawData);
    ~PacketPlayerPosition();

    char* SerializeData();

private:
    char header;
    int m_id;
    float m_posX;
    float m_posY;
    float m_posZ;

}
```

The way I see it, create it in the first way let transmit the packet easily in the TCP stream UDP packet by just casting it back and forth to char array, but on the other end, it's difficult to manage and pass it around in the bigger server architecture. The second way may even allow to create an hierarchy and use polymorphism to pass it around and manage it in the bigger server picture, but, each packet have to implement serialize/deserialize functions in the class, which seems dirty.

Can someone give a "real world" example of an opensource project or just explain why one way preferred on the other?

Comment: There should be some extra work anyway to manage endianness, so you can't simply use `reinterpret_cast` on the packet buffer.

Comment: You might be interested in something like [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: Here's an example [using Boost.ASIO and Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) (scroll down to the example header `Serialization`).

Comment: Other things that will break the simply-cast-object-pointer-to-char-pointer approach:  different integer widths on different architectures (e.g. 32-bit vs 32-bit) and different padding between fields (depending on architecture, compiler settings, etc)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You're right that part can happen too, it seems like the other approach is more practical to use. By the way, you meant 32 bit vs 64 bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is likely to depend on the number of different packet types you are going to need.

If you only need a small number but want hierarchy then use a C++ object. You will duplicate code in the case of the serialize function but you will gain the advantages you mentioned. This makes the code more manageable.

This method requires lots of serialize functions and so will lead to duplicated code each time you add a new type of packet but not so much if that packet descends from another.

If you have lots of different packets to send then use the instantly-serializable c struct. This method avoids duplicating serialize code but will not allow polymorphism and so each time you add another packet that could be a descendant of another packet, you will excessively duplicate code.

So, Objects: less code if most packets can inherit mostly from another.

Structs: less code if most packets cannot inherit.

The question therefore is; how many of your packets can inherit from other packets?